# How to clone a space in Bluemix

Tags: space, ibm-cloud, organization

How to clone a space in Bluemix

- Keeping the same organization, but clone the space?
- or cloning the organization?
  We have several developers working on similar stuff, therefore i am seeking for an easy way to duplicate or clone a "master organization" or space. Both would be sufficient. What would be the easiest way.

Comment: When you say clone a space do you mean copy the membership for one space to another?  Or do you mean copy apps from one to another?

Comment: copy apps...we have an organization and some spaces under this one. Now I would like to copy the apps from one space to another. The org is the whole project, the spaces would be several developers or somehow parts. So we would like to give each developer the same basic set, probably including mockups etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to clone orgs or spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so we would not have to try.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only solution you have right now is to automatize runtime and services provisioning, apps deployment and configuration via script. So it is easy to reproduce the environment in any org/space you need as many times as you need.

Of course, it requires manual work to create those scripts the first time, but usually are part of a Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery solution.